# Flask-Admin: A blueprint's name collision occurred ... Both share the same name "admin"

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have a Flask 0.12.4 app and am using [Flask-Admin](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I get this error intermittently when developing locally, and have just started seeing it in one of our public environments too.

```bash
AssertionError: A blueprint's name collision occurred between 
<flask.blueprints.Blueprint object at 0x7f5cd31f96d0> and 
<flask.blueprints.Blueprint object at 0x7f5cd33b0d90>.
Both share the same name "admin".
Blueprints that are created on the fly need unique names.
```

The steps to reproduce in my development environment are slightly odd:

1. Break some of the admin config (e.g. change one of the strings relating to a column name in `form_columns` so it refers to a non-existent name)
2. Refresh the browser to see the regular "unknown field" error
3. Revert the change
4. Refresh the browser again - you then see the blueprint error above

The line which is causing the error is this one:

```
# admin.py
admin = flask_admin.Admin(
    app, index_view=MyIndexView(), template_mode="bootstrap3"
)
```

Comment: Good edit, @halfer.  I hadn't meant to imply urgency in terms of wanting an urgent answer, just some context as to why I only now bothered trying to fix this!  But that wasn't obvious from my post, so your edit is a good one, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Sam. I try to bear that distinction in mind when I edit (and it's probably why I didn't also comment) but some readers can misinterpret such remarks even if a question author was only referring to their own urgencies `:-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seemed like the line in question was being called multiple times (although the file it's in is only imported in one place).  I tried passing a custom `endpoint` in the `Admin` constructor and continued to get the same error but with the new endpoint name, which suggested that was the case.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42914723/328817) refers in passing to the same problem, and to the solution of using [`init_app`](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_base/#flask_admin.base.Admin.init_app) rather than passing the `app` to the constructor.

Doing that, my code then looked like this, and the error went away:

```
# admin.py
# Notice I'm not passing app here any more.
admin = flask_admin.Admin(index_view=MyIndexView(), template_mode="bootstrap3")
```

```
# app.py
admin.init_app(app) # This line is new
```

I don't understand the detail of how the problem occurred or exactly why this solved it, so any further pointers welcome!

Answer (score 0):

to me help some idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42914723/1262058). Flask-admin 1.5.3

```
# token.__init__.py  <-- token - my app
# endpoint - very important
from app.model import blueprint, Token
from db import db

blueprint = Blueprint("token", __name__, url_prefix='/token')

blueprint.custom_model_views = []
blueprint.custom_model_views += [ModelView(Token, db.session, endpoint='token-admin')]

# admin.__init__.py
def create_module(admin, app, **kwargs):
    admin.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context() as e:
        from app import token
        views = token.blueprint.custom_model_views
        for v in views:
            admin.add_view(v)

# root.__init__.py
flask_admin = Admin()

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])

    from .token import create_module as token_create_module
    from .admin import create_module as admin_create_module

    token_create_module(app)
    admin_create_module(flask_admin, app)

    return app
```

check http://localhost:5000/admin/token-admin/